# Are there tools to see why some questions are really popular?

Tags: discussion

We have some questions with >1k views, but most of the questions are not as popular. Are there tools to see why questions like

[Is there any proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra that can be introduced to undergraduates who have just completed Calc III?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/is-there-any-proof-of-the-fundamental-theorem-of-algebra-that-can-be-introduced)

[Lecturers "(intentional) mistakes" as a teaching tool](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1598/lecturers-intentional-mistakes-as-a-teaching-tool)

[Optimization problems that today's students might actually encounter?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1550/optimization-problems-that-todays-students-might-actually-encounter)

are really popular?

I also included the new tag 'meta-statistics' for questions concerned with the (beta) statistics of MESE itself.

Comment: Part of it is because of the "Hot Network Questions" bit on the right; if they're popular on our site, they'll be shown to people across SE.

Comment: I've shared quite a few on reddit, frquently getting a few thousand views. Here is my profile; most of the recent posts (not comments) are from here: http://www.reddit.com/user/brirush/

Comment: Your first example was shared on reddit, and the other two were hot network questions.

Comment: I would not know of any tool for particular posts (besides searching for links to them and to infer it). There is some data on the overall sources of traffic of the site provided to moderators. We are asked not to share the details so I do not want to go into detail, but I assume it is alright if I confirm that Mike and Brian Rushton have identified the main sources.

Comment: @quid: I'd consider this to be an answer to my question.

Comment: I am glad the information is useful. Thus I reposted it in more selfcontained form as answer.

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77138/is-there-any-analytics-information-that-moderators-can-access-for-individual-que

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not know of any tool for particular posts (besides searching for links to them and to infer it; using the question id can be useful here).

There is some data on the overall sources of traffic of the site provided to moderators. However, we are asked not to share the details so I do not want to go into detail. But I assume it is alright if I confirm that Mike and Brian Rushton have identified the main sources of our traffic as being the rest of the network, especially Stack Overflow, and reddit.

Answer (score 1):

If you earn the [moderator-tools privilege](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), then you can access at least a small statistics where you can order the questions by view: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=stats